# Get the ID of an imgur image

Tags: php, imgur

Here are some examples of imgur links:

```
https://imgur.com/gallery/s2Bqq
https://i.imgur.com/26xcQUF.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/rfw7jrU.gif
http://i.imgur.com/rfw7jrU.gifv
```

The imgur API [specifically asks for the ID](https://api.imgur.com/models/image) of the image (`s2Bqq`, `26xcQUF`, etc), but offers no way, from what I've seen, to get the ID of an image given a link.

So my question is, how would I, using PHP, get the ID of any imgur link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the last component of the path and remove any extension on it.

One approach:

```
$id = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `parse_url()` you can obtain all your information:

```
print_r(parse_url('https://i.imgur.com/26xcQUF.jpg'));

Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => i.imgur.com
    [path] => /26xcQUF.jpg
)
```

In this case just do:

```
echo substr( $array['path'],1,-4);
```

Live: http://ideone.com/0N6cmj

Comment: The `substr()` bit will work incorrectly for links that don't have an extension, or which have extensions which aren't exactly three characters long.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be done using regular expressions

A simple example would be `^.+/([^/]+)(\.[^/]+)?$` which matches the last part of the url, minus any extension present.

To use it in PHP, `preg_match('#^.+/([^/]+)(\.[^/]+)?$#', $url, $matches)` and `$matches[1]` will have the id.