# Get imgur ID from URL

Tags: php, regex

How would I get the ID from a given imgur URL. Here are some examples of the different types of URLs:

```
https://imgur.com/gallery/arP2Otg
https://i.imgur.com/ycArzxR.jpg
http://imgur.com/SyuKFYj
```

As far as I know, the length of the IDs vary.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003793/get-the-id-of-an-imgur-image) was previously asked here on SE, but it's not flawless.

For example, the URL `https://imgur.com/SyuKFYj&` does not work with the answer given to that question. Notice the `&` appended to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to extract the word chars at the start exists in  last part.

```
preg_match('~/\K\w+(?=[^/]*$)~m', 'https://imgur.com/SyuKFYj', $id);
echo $id[0];
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sM7bO6/1)

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/QcETX3)

Comment: Are you sure that's right? I'm trying it on the URL `http://imgur.com/SyuKFYj`, but it's just returning `1` when I print it out. I've set up this to test it on: http://regexr.com/3bd1e

Comment: @user4454001 regexr site is designed for js not for php. Check the link I attached.

Comment: Nevertheless, its' still only returning `1` when I try to return `preg_match('~/\K\w+(?=[^/]*$)~', 'https://imgur.com/SyuKFYj')`.

Comment: @user4454001 check my update. You have to print the match.

Comment: It's not returning anything now: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8eac3d90cd86171deaf0a17615a358ea885479f0

Comment: `echo match` gives error `Array to string conversion`: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b0681d6bb65ac3b2b619cc2511d482ee7783e4f

Comment: Figured it out. It should be `preg_match('/\/\K\w+(?=[^\/]*$)/', 'https://imgur.com/SyuKFYj&', $match);` Then I can do `echo $match[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was how can you tell whether the trailing character is part of the ID or not.  As far as I can tell imgur IDs are always odd length.  The links sometimes contain a trailing character to denote size (or something else), so after you strip everything between the last / and . in the link, you also need to strip the trailing character if the length is 6, 8, ...

```
var u = 'https://i.imgur.com/ycArzxR.jpg';
var s = u.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var d = (u + '.').indexOf('.', s);
var id = u.substring(s, d - ((d - s + 1) % 2));
```